# Which ports to block, to cripple NFS

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a NFS mount; and I would like to block the traffic to this resource, without unmount it.

Which one is the port (or which are the ports), to block, to avoid that a process will write on NFS? I see taht nfsd is on 1110, but I am not sure about other ports.

Comment: Should I see NFS when I run this command?

Comment: Yes (if you run it on the server, of course..). Also try with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks, Although I just see portmapper on tcp and udp on port 111. NFS resource is mounted, since I can access it. (BTW you mean that I need to run this on the NFS server? What about the client that uses the NFS resource?)

Comment: NFS is a blocking I/O if mounted hard. You've been warned.